# How does one add numbers to an admin menu?

Tags: plugins, menus

I am trying to make a plugin and want to surface concerns in the admin panel menu row for my plugin, similar to the below screenshot from Wordfence.

[image: Wordfence menu with the number 2 in a yellow circle]

I have searched around Google, but all point me to making menus for users on the blog, or other odd items.

Comment: This is really vague tough to answer, because no one knows where you'd be getting the alert count from... ...start off with getting the admin item in the dashboard navigation https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I dont know how much specific I can be. Other plugins (like Wordfence) are displaying notifications in their menu name, to show a number. I would like to do the same, and need help. Is this site not here to provide help?

Answer (score 0):

Found this and it helped: https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/notification-counter-bubbles.html

```
$notification_count = 2; // here we get the count somehow in the code
add_menu_page(
    'Tickets',
    $notification_count ? sprintf( 'Tickets <span class="awaiting-mod">%d</span>', $notification_count ) : 'Tickets',
    'manage_options',
    'tickets_page_slug',
    'tickets_page_handler'
);
```